# Short SQL challenge with 3 tables, max/group by, join and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

Given 3 tables with columns below...

table (columns)

> A (a_pk, b_pk, other)
>
> B (b_pk, a_pk, c_pk)
>
> C (c_pk, b_pk, date)

(comment: pk is a primary key, date is a date)

...I'm trying to select...

> A.a_pk, A.other, C.date

...with the following restrictions:

> max(B.b_pk) group by B.a_pk (only select the maximum of B.b_pk for every A.a_pk)
>
> A.other = 'something'      (just a WHERE example)
>
> ORDER BY C.date             (order by latest dates)

Below is one attempt without success (others looked even more screwed up)

```
SELECT A.a_pk, A.other, C.date
FROM A, C
WHERE   
 A.other = 'something'
 AND
 A.a_pk IN 
  (
  SELECT max(B.b_pk), B.a_pk, B.c_pk, C.date
  FROM B
  INNER JOINT C ON C.b_pk = B.b_pk
  GROUP BY B.a_kp
  )
ORDER BY C.date DESC
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
     Select A.a_pk, A.other, C.date
     From A Left Join (B Join C On C.b_pk = B.b_pk)
         On B.a_pk = A.a_pk
             And B.b_pk = 
                 (Select Max(b_pk)
                  From B
                  Where a_pk = A.a_pk)
     Order By C.Date
```

Comment: Why use a LEFT JOIN?  Also, don't you need to join B and C on both `b_pk` and `c_pk`?  Actually, it isn't wholly clear from the question whether you do or not.

Comment: Used an outer join cause I wasn;t sure if it was possible to not have a B record for each A record... And as to pks, yes it is not clear from question as to whether the columns named with _pk are only part of a composite pk for that tyable, or FKs to a PK in another table...

Comment: Chapeau! I just tested it positiv. Thx a lot!

Comment: I tested it positiv with primary keys used as foreign keys in other tables. (and skipped C.b_pk, which doesn't make sence in that case and joined C on C.c_pk = B.c_pk)